# Does the limit exist? Limit going to $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I tried to solve an exercise

Does $\lim\limits_{x, y\to\ (0,0)} \frac{(e^{x+y} - 1)}{x^2+y^2}$ exist?

I was thinking about looking at $(x, 0), (0,y)$ and $x=y=t$ and say it doesn't exist but i was told its not a proof. So could you please let me know how to solve this and this kind of questions? Thank you

Comment: If you have a counter example that is a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:  $\dfrac{e^{x+y}-1}{x^2+y^2} = \dfrac{e^{x+y}-1}{x+y}\cdot \dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$. So the limit depends on the ratio $\dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$ that has no limit !

Comment: Wow it was that easy? Thank you so much

Comment: @werlless: My pleasure.